# Alloy: correct way to create and use a ListView?

Tags: listview, titanium, titanium-alloy

What is the proper way to separate the view and controller with Alloy?

`someController.js:`

`$.list.setSections(sections);`,
I know this populates a ListView with id='list' in the XML markup...

or

`var list = Ti.UI.createListView({stuff})`
and then somehow push the list out to the view.

I am not sure what the best way is to keep in spirit with MVC.

Comment: The doc guide is marginally helpful, although it created more questions than it answered, for me that is. You can try it though. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_ListView_Guide-section-40928632_AlloyListViewGuide-AssigningDataProgrammaticallytoaListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using alloy, you should create the list in XML, in the actual view file. then you can do stuff with it in the controller using $.list, as you do in your first option.

Comment: Thanks Damian. So the list is not created in the controller; it is created in XML and manipulated using $.list?

Comment: that's correct. if the list is going to display a collection, you can also declare the collection in the XML using <Collection src="youCollection" /> and then fetch the collection in the controller using var collection = Alloy.Collections.yourCollection; collection.fetch();